# jQuery setTimeout or delay ajax spinner

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it posible to `setTimeout` on `beforeSend` so ajax spinner will spin 4 seconds ? Or I have to use differed function to do that?

The reason I wanna do that is because some times for is processing so fast that user cant even see the effect with ajax spinner.

```
var v = $("#contact-form").validate({
 submitHandler: function(form) {
   $(form).ajaxSubmit({
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('.submit-btn button').addClass('loading');
   },
    url: 'send-mail.php',
    success: function() {
    $('.submit-btn button').addClass('message-sent');
    },
   complete: function() {
    $('.submit-btn button').removeClass('loading').text('Send');   }
   });     
   v.resetForm();
 }
})
```

Comment: You want your users to think your server is slow ? I usually do the opposite : I don't display the spinner in the first 500 ms after I sent the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using an animation [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/). However this is not recommended. I mean you want to make a fast user interface, so why would I as a user be forced to wait 4 seconds if the server interaction has finished much faster?

The graphics side of it may look tempting, but from a UX point of view, just leave it as it is.